# Socket.io with PM2 Cluster in production - websocket vs sticky session

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, load-balancing, pm2

I'm a bit confused. I'm using socket.io on my NodeJS Server using a simple:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo();
io.attach(server);
io.adapter(redisAdapter(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL));
server.listen(3000)
```

Now I clustered my server process using PM2 Cluster option.

My nginx configuration is straight forward as follows:

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5030;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

Should I also add `websocket` transport instead of the normal http polling?

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo();
io.attach(server, {
   transports: [ 'websocket' ]
});
io.adapter(redisAdapter(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL));
server.listen(3000)
```

In socket.io website they recommend **against** it and they suggest instead to balance load between nodes using `upstream` in the `nginx.conf` file with sticky session as follows:

```
upstream nodes {
    # enable sticky session based on IP
    ip_hash;

    server app01:3000;
    server app02:3000;
    server app03:3000;
  }
```

But my I don't have `app01`, `app02` and `app03`. I have my PM2 processes, but they all reside on the same `localhost:5030` address. So am I left only with the choice of enabling `websocket` transport and losing the fallback option for long-polling?

Comment: did you found a solution? I'm facing the same error

Comment: xersus did you found any solutions?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately

Comment: Any luck? I've been reading into https://socket.io/docs/v3/using-multiple-nodes/index.html

Comment: Actually you need to use the fork mode for nginx approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream nodes {
  hash $remote_addr consistent;
  server yourhost.com:3000;
  server yourhost.com:3001;
  server yourhost.com:3002;
}
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://nodes;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

You need to use nginx as a load balancer and switch to fork mode and of course you gonna use different ports
about cluster mode we need another solution